# Getting an image path to use in converting to base 64 string

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, image

I have an image in my images folder

[image]

and I want to pass this image to an Image object so I can then convert it to a base 64 string. This will then be passed to the client and inserted into the src of a img element.

The problem is that I don't know how to get the image from disk into the image object.

```
Image img = Image.FromFile(@"..Images\no_image.jpg"); // doesn't work

string image = Convert.ToBase64String(imageToByteArray(img));


public byte[] imageToByteArray(Image imageIn)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        imageIn.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: Did you try `Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath("/Images/no_image.jpg"))`?

Comment: Why would you pass it as a string? its a picture.

Comment: Try using `Server.MapPath("~/Images/no_image.jpg")`. Also: "doesn't work" is never a useful description, always say HOW it doesn't work, e.g. what error occurs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you work on a web project, you should use:

```
Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath("~/Images/no_image.jpg"))
```

else if it is a WinForm/WPF/Console application, use:

```
Image.FromFile(System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Images", "no_image.jpg"))
```

Comment: What's the namespace for Server. I can't get intellisense to recognize it.

Comment: Server is a property in Controller so in a controller action you can use `this.Server.MapPath` outside the controller you could use `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath`